# echo function with the html tags

Tags: php

I want to create tags using echo function but I'm stuck here; I dont know how to make it through.

This is what I want to do:

```
echo "<img src=$row['one'] style="width:100px"/>" ;
```

(Note: `$row['one']` is a variable of php script and that contains the path of the image), but it throws me these error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\im.php on line 13
```

I want these statement to execute in php and I tried this way too:

```
echo '<img src=$row['one'] styel="width:100px" />';
```

These time I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\im.php on line 13
```

I know where the error is. The error is most probably here

```
'<img src=$row[' //here's the error, right?
```

I worked on c and quite some other languages.  I know that in c, to use double quotes in the printf we follow up some syntax but I dont know what to do in php.

Comment: it can be `$row[one]`, but it needs to be in double quotes in order to be parsed.

Comment: @webarto: You *really* should quote all strings (including the string used as an array index).

Comment: @Rocket not in the case mentioned though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `"`:

```
echo "<img src=\"{$row['one']}\" style=\"width:100px\" />";
```

or you use single quotes and do this:

```
echo '<img src="', $row['one'], '" style="width:100px" />';
```

There is never a need to concatenate in order to echo. You can always just use `,`. The php manual explains the [differences between `'` and `"` in the chapter on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

As a goodie, because you mentioned [printf](http://www.php.net/printf), this works in php, too:

```
printf('<img src="%s" style="width:100px"/>', $row['one']);
```

Comment: for your noisy "no need to concatenate"

Comment: Well, thats kind of strange. I added it to the answers proposing concatenation because it is in fact not needed and this fact should be noticed when viewing an answer (possibly in isolation). BTW: upvotes should only refer to the answer, not if you like someones behaviour, face etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "<img src=$row['one'] style="width:100px"/>" ;
```

You cannot have (unescaped) double quotes inside double quotes.  It should be:

```
echo "<img src='{$row['one']}' style='width:100px'/>" ;
```

Some notes:  HTML attributes can be quoted using either single or double quotes.  Double quotes expand variables (single quotes don't).  Putting variable names in `{}` helps when using arrays.

Comment: @niko: What do you mean "does not work"?  What doesn't work?  If this doesn't work, then something else is wrong.

Comment: sorry its my mistake its working @Rocket I can give you +1 but middus help is more appreciated because it easily stucked my mind becuase I know how to handle printf

Answer (score 3):

You need to concatenate the string.

```
 echo "<img src='".$row['one']."' style='width:100px'/>" ;
```

You are also mixing your quotes up,

```
// Bad: echo "<img... style="width:100px"/>";
```

You have to be mindful of which quotes you are using to create the string. You are using the double quotations to both create the string, and define your width. You can fix this by escaping the quotes used to write the width, ex: \"width:100px\", or you can use single quotes like in my example.

Comment: No need to concat, see my answer. Also '"' should be used for HTML attributes.

Comment: @middus: You can quote HTML attributes using either single or double quotes, it doesn't matter.

Comment: You're right, there is not a _need_ to concat, but it is useful information to know, and it will definitely come up in the future. I'm also not a huge fan of the {$phpVar} syntax, so I suppose that I prefer this method :). *Somehow the saying "Potatoes, Potatoes" doesn't port over to the web very well.

Comment: @Rocket Yes, you can -- but who does? Somehow most people tend to use `"`. It's not mandatory, but kind of a convention.

Comment: @KurtFunai Of course, it will come in handy, but it's not needed for this task. `{}` allows to use arrays inside `"`, so that's why I used it. What's wrong about it in your opinion?

Comment: @middus: Who does?  People who don't feel like escaping quotes.  For example `$a = "<a href='$href'>Test</a>"` is easier than `$a = "<a href=\"$href\">Test</a>"`.

Comment: @Rocket So you'll have a mixed codebase? I use HEREDOC for longer HTML to avoid the quoting problem.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with it, I just prefer to concatenate for readability/maintenance purposes. I've been reading a bit more about this topic in general, and seems that using commas with echo has some performance gains.

Comment: @Rocket I agree with you in terms of readability, that is why I prefer to use single quotes instead of escaping.

Comment: @middus: Single quotes vs double quotes can be useful when writing HTML and not echoing it from PHP.  For example `<img src='img.png' title='This is a "cool" image'>`.

Comment: @KurtFunai Maybe here: http://www.phpbench.com/ (Conclusion of "echo vs. print"). Have an upvote for your explanation (and the comments).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<img src='" . $row['one'] . "' style='width:100px'/>" ;
```

Comment: There is no need to concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create tags using echo function

That's wrong desire.
Do not use echo to create tags. Tags belongs to HTML, not to PHP.
So, just write usual HTML, bereaking it for PHP only when needed.

```
<img src="<?=$row['one']?>" style="width:100px"/>
```

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste. But this is a valid alternative, so +1.

Comment: This "matter of taste" is accepted as a general templating solution by the most of major PHP frameworks. Ever hear of trmplates?

Comment: I've got the feeling that you're trying to provoke me. Why the vitriol? There's no need for that. Of course I've heard of templates. However, you don't know about the OP's situation and maybe it makes sense in his case to use echo.

Comment: naw, I am merely asking you if you ever heard of using templates for HTML output instead of echoing it from within PHP without syntax highlighting, syntax autocompletion, quotes mixing and such.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel is right, this is bad on so many levels, and is making PHP look childish comparing to other languages :) Yes, PHP was built to do that (Personal Home Page), but that was long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<img src=\"{$row[one]}\" style=\"width:100px\" />";
```